# How to load a different view depending on which table view cell was pressed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

In my app, I need to load a different view for each cell in my table view when it is pressed. I have tried the code below, but my app fails when the cell is pressed.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell.textLabel.text == @"Area")
    {
        ThirdViewController *tvController = [[ThirdViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:tvController animated:YES];
    }
}
```

note that I have imported the 'thirdviewcontroller.h' file in the implementation file that code is in.

I am still getting used to coding with obj-c and Xcode, so please excuse me if I've tried something completely dumb/stupid. If you need more information, please let me know, so that my question is not closed.

I have also searched around, but nothing I have found seems to be helpful to me.

Thanks

Comment: Have you `NSLog`'d inside the if to see if those lines ever get executed?

Comment: Found my problem... Just did the log and didn't receive an output. Means my code is bogus then...

Comment: Glad you found it. Using `NSLog` is one of the easiest and most frequently used debugging techniques for me. You could also use breakpoints instead of `NSLog`ging. You may want to check into [`DLog`](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/debugging/the-evolution-of-a-replacement-for-nslog), which spits out the file, method and line number from which the log is ejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna add a modalviewcontroller based on what cell you clicked on.
You know u have populated the tableview with an array, yes?

Well do something like this:

```
if ( [listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] == someStatement)
{
    YourVC = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];

    self.YourVc.dismissDelegate = self;

    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                               initWithRootViewController:self.YourVc];

    navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet; //or any of the other presentationstyles.

    [self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];

    [self.addTableViewController release];
    [navController release];
}
```

This will make a new viewcontroller appear based on the selection you made.

Comment: listOfItems is my array, I'm assuming? As for YourVC, if you don't mind, which view controller is that for? The table view or the target view?

Comment: listOfItems is your datasource. The array you use to populate the tableview with.
YourVC = YourViewController meaning any custom ViewController you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have almost done it. To compare the test you need to use:

```
[cell.textLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Area"]
```

However, it is better to rely on `indexPath` rather then on `textLabel`.

Also, do not forget to release `tvController`.